# Setting multiple Apache2 VirtualHosts to use same DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2

First, this seems to be working fine on my server, but I am wondering about any "unknown" implications, especially any public-facing problems that could occur, such as "Google now hates your server..."

I have about 10 domains which are just serving a simple "We're offline" message.

I want all of these "offline" `<VirtualHosts>` to use the same `<DocumentRoot>`, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example1.com
      ServerAlias www.example1.com
      DocumentRoot /www/_offline.com
   <Directory /www/_offline.com>
      ...[snip]...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example2.com
      ServerAlias www.example2.com
      DocumentRoot /www/_offline.com
   <Directory /www/_offline.com>
      ...[snip]...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I going to have any problems with this setup, or is this actually okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fine.  You can optimise this somewhat by just using `ServerAlias` directives for all of your FQDNs in the one vhost, but it's not required.

Comment: Thanks womble. Would you mind giving me an example of that?

Comment: Uhm... ServerAlias example1.com; ServerAlias www.example1.com; ServerAlias example2.com; ServerAlias www.example2.com...

Comment: ServerAlias www.example3.com<cr>ServerAlias www.example4.com<cr> (and so on). Much less bloat. Please mark womble's response as the correct answer :)

Comment: For the record, I don't think I can do that because I need logging set up for each site independently. Many thanks, however. I'll ask my Edit question in a new post.